# R function that makes several changes to multiple columns

Tags: r, function

Whenever I run a query on the data warehouse or receive data from colleagues I get data in the following format:

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993), Company = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), Sales = c("100,1", "101,1", 
"102,2", "103,3"), Revenue = c("100,1", "101,1", "102,2", "103,3"
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

The first thing I must do is to replace "," with "." and the convert to numeric. So far I've done it like this:

```
df$Sales <- gsub(",", ".", df$Sales)
df$Sales <- as.numeric(df$Sales)
```

This gets tiresome when there are multiple columns to convert and they have different names from case to case. So, after doing this for the nth time on the nth dataset I decided to write my first R function from scratch.
My initial attempt did this in two steps, and it worked!

```
# Columns to convert
columns_names <- c("Revenue", "Sales")

# Function to convert "," to "."
convert_to_dot <- function(x, column){
  for (i in column){
    df[[i]] <- gsub(",", ".", x[[i]])
  }
  df
}

# Function to convert to numeric
convert_to_numeric <- function(x, column){
  for (i in column){
    df[[i]] <- as.numeric(as.character(x[[i]]))
  }
  df
}
df <- convert_to_dot(df, columns_names)
df <- convert_to_numeric(df, columns_names)

structure(list(Year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993), Company = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), Sales = c(100.1, 101.1, 102.2, 
103.3), Revenue = c(100.1, 101.1, 102.2, 103.3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

However, when I try to combine them into one function nothing works. I have tried several versions of the following but they all tend to yield similar results where either the values in the columns are replaced with NAs or the whole data frame turns into a NULL value.

```
# Function to replace "," with "." and convert to numeric
convert_dot_numeric <- function(x, column){
  for (i in column){
    df[[i]] <- gsub(",", ".", x[[i]])
    df[[i]] <- as.numeric(as.character(x[[i]]))
  }
  df
}

structure(list(Year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993), Company = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), Sales = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), Revenue = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm guessing that for loops aren't the most efficient way of doing this, but can anyone give me a hint to how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace x[[i]] to df[[i]] as you already changed the comma with dot gsub using gsub. so your function should be:

**Using OP approach(correcting the function):**

```
# Function to replace "," with "." and convert to numeric
convert_dot_numeric <- function(x, column){
    for (i in column){
        df[[i]] <- gsub(",", ".", x[[i]])
        df[[i]] <- as.numeric(as.character(df[[i]]))
    }
    df
}

convert_dot_numeric(df,c('Sales', 'Revenue') )
```

**Using lapply:**

You can use **lapply** to do it also like below:

```
df[,c('Sales', 'Revenue')] <- lapply(df[,c('Sales', 'Revenue')], function(x)as.numeric(gsub(',', '.', x)))
```

lapply would iterate to all the necessary columns which you provide as input, then  gsub can replace the commas to dot iteratively. You can totally avoid for loop here (if you need to).

**Ouput**:

> ```
> #  Year Company Sales Revenue
> #1 1990       A 100.1   100.1
> #2 1991       B 101.1   101.1
> #3 1992       C 102.2   102.2
> #4 1993       D 103.3   103.3
> ```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I would use `readr::parse_number()` and set the decimal mark to a comma.  You can apply the change to multiple variables with `dplyr::mutate_at()`.

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Sales, Revenue), parse_number, locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","))

  Year Company Sales Revenue
1 1990       A 100.1   100.1
2 1991       B 101.1   101.1
3 1992       C 102.2   102.2
4 1993       D 103.3   103.3
```

If you want you can wrap it up in a function:

```
treat_commas <- function(data, ...) {

data %>%
  mutate_at(vars(...), parse_number, locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","))

}

treat_commas(df, Sales, Revenue)

  Year Company Sales Revenue
1 1990       A 100.1   100.1
2 1991       B 101.1   101.1
3 1992       C 102.2   102.2
4 1993       D 103.3   103.3
```